# Combining code that forces user to enable macro and code that makes cells mandatory

Tags: vba, excel

Big thanks to A.S.H for helping me with out with this code earlier.

Right now, I'm attempting to show a splash sheet that tells users to enable macros in order to access the workbook. The plan is to save the file with the splash sheet visible and other sheets veryhidden during the BeforeClose event. During the Open event, the splash sheet will be made veryhidden and the other sheets will be made visible.

Hence, the user will only see the splash sheet when he/she opens the file with macros disabled. However with the below code, it doesn't seem as though the routine that makes the splash sheet visible and the rest veryhidden is running. Where have I gone wrong?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rs As Object, ws As Object
Dim Ans As Integer
Dim target As Range, r As Range
Set rs = Sheets("Report")
If Me.Saved = False Then
    Do
        Ans = MsgBox("Do you want to save the changes you made to '" & _
            Me.Name & "'?", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)
        Select Case Ans
            Case vbYes
                With rs
                    Set target = .Range("B5:R" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
                End With
                target.Value = Application.Trim(target.Value)
                For Each r In target.Rows
                    If Not IsEmpty(r.Cells(1)) And Application.CountIf(r, "") > 0 Then
                        Cancel = True
                        r.Parent.Activate: r.Activate
                        MsgBox ("Please confirm all required fields have been completed")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Sheets("Reminder").Visible = xlSheetVisible
                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If ws.Name <> "Reminder" Then
                        ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
                    End If
                Next ws
                ActiveWorkbook.Save
                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If ws.Name <> "Reminder" Then
                        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                    End If
                Next ws
                Sheets("Reminder").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
                ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case vbNo
                Me.Saved = True
            Case vbCancel
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    Loop Until ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That you cannot run VBA code if macros are disabled? Obviously, this cannot be fixed using VBA, otherwise that security measure would be pointless.

Comment: The other part of my code shows the actual sheets and hides the splash sheet if macros are enabled. That way, if macros are disabled, they cannot see the actual sheets.

Comment: If macros are disabled how will any of your code run ?

Comment: This still doesn't explain what you are trying to achieve. Please explicitly state what you want to do and what problems arise.

Comment: I want to ensure that the user will fill in the mandatory cells, hence I used the above coding. That is why I need the user to enable macros. If the user does not enable macros, then he/she cannot access the workbook. Once the user enables macros, he/she will be able to access the workbook.

Comment: Right now, I'm stuck at the coding that only shows the splash sheet when the workbook is open with macros not enabled.

Comment: What else would you expect to happen? Remember, with macros deactivated, there is **no way VBA code gets executed on startup!**

Comment: When the workbook is saved during the BeforeClose event, the other sheets are veryhidden while the splash sheet is unhidden. That is why on startup, the user will only see the splash sheet if macros aren't activated! If macros are activated, the workbook Open event will make the splash sheet veryhidden and unhide the other sheets!

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing screen trouble, it is likely due to some erroneous manipulation of `Application.ScreenUpdating` here and in other macros. In this one, the error is that you first set it to `False` and then `Exit Sub` without restoring it to `True`.

Moreover, since your routine only does calculation (checking) and does not change cell values, there's no point in disabling `Application.ScreenUpdating`.

On a side note, I think your routine that checks for empty cells can be much simplified.

```
Function dataIsValid() As Boolean
    Dim target As Range, r As Range
    With ActiveSheet ' <-- May be better change to some explicit sheet name
        Set target = .Range("B5:R" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    target.value = Application.Trim(target.value) ' <-- trim the whole range
    For Each r In target.Rows
        If Not IsEmpty(r.Cells(1)) And Application.CountIf(r, "") Then
            r.Parent.Activate: r.Activate ' <-- Show erroneous row
            MsgBox ("Please confirm all required fields have been completed")
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    dataIsValid = True
End Function

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = Not dataIsValid
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = Not dataIsValid
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks A.S.H, how can I simplify the routine?

Comment: @bananas see my edit for answer. Idea is using array excel functions and ranges. The proposed routine also does additional useful things ;)

Comment: @A.S.H r.Parent.Activate: r.Activate is rather new to me. I checked out what it does and I'm just wondering if it can highlight more than one row. Thanks again.

Comment: @bananas no, just the first row found. Your routine was made such that it exits at the first invalid data. This statement is two statements, the first is to activate the sheet, the second the row. I made it like this hoping later you will test an explicit sheet name and stop counting on the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: @ShaiRado hey :).... we should get a life :P  but yeah, i'm doing other stuff actually but SO is always active on my laptop ;)

Comment: @ A.S.H Got it. Sorry if it seems like I need you to hold my hand through everything, but I'm rather hopeless at this. Your code works wonderfully but I'm running into a slight issue which if I close the workbook with changes, it will prompt me if I want to save, at which I'll press save. but then the msgbox pops out and after clicking ok, the workbook closes. is there a line of code that stops the closing of the workbook?

Comment: @bananas yeah I see. This routine cancels the *Saving* but not the *Closing*. What you want is to cancel the latter. So, just change your routine's prototype to this: `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)`. See edited version.

Comment: Or if you want both, put both event handlers (but think of factorizing the validation in a single function `Function dataIsValid() As Boolean`).

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it that way. I think that this is what you need. @bananas

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks Ash, please see my edited post above. I tried to go about it slightly differently by emulating excel's save prompt when a user tries to close with changes unsaved (just an extra step). The coding that checks the data is perfect, but the routine that makes the splash sheet visible and other sheets veryhidden doesn't seem to be working as planned.

Comment: @bananas Friendly, the question should not be edited radically as we proceed, as this violates the rule of SO and the question may be deleted by moderators. When a good progress is made, I think you'd better ask a new question :)

Comment: @A.S.H Got it, I'm going to close this and then open a new question. Thanks again.